# Copper line to fridge

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, copper-tubing, ice-maker, leaking

The copper line in my fridge is cracked and now is leaking, we’ve turned off sadder line and is still leaking a lot. How can we get it to stop leaking without replacing? We don’t mind if our ice-maker no longer works.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's a "sadder line"? Is there a valve between the water supply and the fridge supply line? Could you add a picture or two of the leaking area and/or the valve (if there is one)?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a saddle valve clamp that is closed yet still letting water through, you may simply have to turn the handle a bit more with force to drive the pin tighter to the copper pipe.

HOWEVER: If it instead breaks you have a bigger problem to solve.

If you only wish to temporarily block water in a copper tube, squashing it flat with a tight vice grip pliers can work until a replacement saddle clamp (*or better a genuine T fitting with valve*) is installed. A leaking copper tube can easily be spliced unless corrosion was the cause.
There are many variables and I don't have enough info from you to know exactly what is happening and what your ultimate goal is..

Take some cell phone photos to post of the leak and of the valve. Or bring those to the hardware store (*but confirm the skill of the clerk before you listen!*). All the needed parts are easily purchased. It can be fixed by anyone comfortable with a screwdriver and adjustable wrench.

Comment: Saddle valves are crap.  You are correct, The water supply should be turned off and the valve cut out and replaced with a tee and 1/4 turn valve. This will require soldering tools and skills or pipe cutter and sharkbite fittings and the knowledge to use/install them.

Comment: A tube cutter might help too+1